# How to stop a div from breaking the padding of its container?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a component for my website, so I created a container with multiple things inside, including a button (which is the problem).
The button has a width:100% and the container has 20px padding, I want the button to be at the bottom of the container but when I do it, the size of the button becomes the same as the whole width of the container resulting in it overflowing off the container.

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 5%;
    background-color: #171e28;
    padding: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```
#submit{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 8% / 50%;
    background-color: #fc7613;
    font-family: 'Varela Round';
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: is box-sizing also reset for .container ? (real width/height of 400 or 500px ? including or not the padding) . You could use position:sticky instead absolute and top instead bottom. If that are boxes to be all the same, you may also use a flex or grid layout. ex https://jsfiddle.net/r14wsym9/

Answer (score 0):

Setting an element to `position:absolute` will make it ignore its parent's padding.
You can place your button at the bottom like so :

```
  .container{
      padding:20px;
      display:flex;
      
    }
    
    #submit{
      margin-top:auto;
    }
```

or :

```
    .container{
              padding:20px;
              display:flex;
              align-items:flex-end;
            }
```